# Exchange values between two array elements (Simple)

Tags: c#, arrays

Imagine something like this:
I have an array of 4 elements and I want to exchange the value between the element 1 and 3. How can I do this?

```
int[] i = new array[4];

i[0] = 10;
i[1] = 20;
i[2] = 30;
i[3] = 40;

if(something...)
{
  i[1] = i[3]
  i[3] = previous value of i[1]
}
```

I want this:

```
i[0] = 10;
i[1] = 40;
i[2] = 30;
i[3] = 20;
```

ANy idea?

Comment: you should use a temporary variable.

Comment: Do you really not know any way to do it or is this a quiz to do it without a variable or sometihng?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using a temporary variable.

```
if(something...)
{
  var temp = i[1];
  i[1] = i[3];
  i[3] = temp;
}
```